# How did people in Mali know that there were two stars appearing as one in Sirius before telescopes were invented?

Tags: telescope, star-systems

Did they invent a telescope and keep it quiet?
Given that glass has been around for 4000 years (made in mesopotamia in 2000 BC) was it technically possible to polish it and make convex shapes from it a long time ago?

Comment: An European explorer made contact with the after the Sirius B was discovered and told them about it. The story was slowly inserted in their folklore. Most Dogon today confirm that there was no mythology associated with that, though. So, nothing anachronistic at all.

Comment: @PierrePaquette-- would be a good answer if you have sources?

Comment: seeing as you probably weren't there (in Mali before telescopes were invented), we are going to need a *source* for this claim.

Comment: This is more suitable for SE.Sceptic. It is worth noting that Temple was rather selective with his reporting of their beliefs making it sound like a scientifically accurate description of the Sirius system while the original stories apparently were incompatible with observations.

Comment: Sirius B is apparent mag 8.4, so it cannot be seen without a telescope.  There is no planetary nebula, so it did not become a white dwarf recently.